# Why can't blocks be hidden with jQuery?

Tags: css, jquery, block-editor

<sub>This seems to be a trivial CSS question and should be asked on SO, but I think there are many subtleties in here that it's better to ask in here.</sub>

I add a CSS class to a block and use jQuery to hide it. It's simple, but it doesn't work. How do I debug this?

```
<script>$("hidetab").css("display", "none");</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jQuery selector is incorrect.

Try `<script>$(".hidetab").css("display", "none");</script>`

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: My guess then is that the script is being added after the markup is in place. Are you able to wrap it in an IIFE or document.ready? Are you getting any console errors? There's not much to go on here.